# How to use the new function FindCookies?

Tags: functions, web-access

This is a further question of [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123771/how-to-crawl-some-website-needed-username-and-password). Actually this code from [SqRoots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/21504/sqroots).And this code has completed the task.

***(I assume you are using [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) and MMA version 11.0)***

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"];
conn=OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["SQLite",First[FileNames["cookies.sqlite",ParentDirectory[$UserBaseDirectory]<>"\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\",Infinity]]]];
c=SQLExecute[conn,"select * from moz_cookies where baseDomain like '%.stackexchange.com'"];
cookie=<|"Domain"->#[[-3]],"Name"->#[[2]],"Content"->#[[3]],"Path"->#[[-2]],"ExpirationDate"->#[[-1]]|>&/@c[[;;,{2,4,5,6,7,8}]];
t=URLRead["https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/21532/yode?tab=favorites","Body",VerifySecurityCertificates->True,{Cookies->cookie},CharacterEncoding->"UTF-8"];
file=ExpandFileName[Export["testt.txt",t]];
Quiet[DeleteFile[StringReplace[file, "txt" -> "html"]]];
File@RenameFile[file,StringReplace[file,"txt"->"html"]]//SystemOpen
```

After you run this code,you will get the website like:

http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-09-07-17-26-33.png

This is what I want exactly.But I'm a little unhappy with the use of package `DatabaseLink` and that command of SQL.I think we can use the new function `FindCookies` to replace it.But I don't know how to realize it.

**Question:**
How to use `FindCookies` to get that `cookie`?

Answer (score 7):

[More of an extended comment]

The new [cookie functionality](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/CookieManagement.html) in Mathematica 11.0 is built around `CURLLink` / `libcurl`, hence the cookie storage format is the *cookiejar* (Netscape cookie file) which is a plain text file with each cookie on a separate line.

Since Firefox stores the cookies in a `sqlite` database, they would not be directly accessible to `FindCookies` and friends. Of course, there are tools available to export the cookies in this format, but that's similar in spirit to what you are already doing.

Comment: You can show that if it can omit that command of SQL.